# Delete exit comment on the left, and increase menu letter size,Any way to solve the problem?

Tags: front-end, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I have 2 problems, I need to delete the output comments of a special calculation and also see if there is a way to please the letters of the MMA menu, I have searched and read but it has not been clear to me how to do it, if you can.[image]

Comment: To remove the Cell Labels: `Preferences | Advanced | Open Option Inspector | Global Preferences | Cell Options | Cell Labels | ShowCellLabel | False`

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think the font size of menus might be controlled by the operating system and not Mathematica. I know on macOS, the menu bar isn't even part of the notebook window so I think they're definitely controlled by the OS in that case.